# Layover in CDG can I check my luggage through to DUB and go into Paris

Tags: luggage, airports, layovers, cdg, dub

i have a 14 hour layover in CDG (Paris - Charles-De-Gaulle) coming back from BKK (Bangkok airport), can I check my luggage through to DUB (Dublin airport) then leave the airport and go into Paris.

Answer (score 3):

This will depend on your airlines. The airport is irrelevant unless it requires you to claim your baggage and walk them through customs. That is not the case in your scenario.

If both flights are operated by the same airline, the answer is: Yes, you'll be able to check your luggage in at Bangkok airport and all the way through to Dublin.

If it is different airlines and one of them is a budget airline, the answer will almost certainly be: No. You'll need to reclaim your luggage at CDG and check it into the next leg of your trip.

If both airlines are non-budget airlines (and especially if both belong to an airline partnership like Star Alliance) it may be possible to check the luggage through. I've done this with Icelandair on one hand and Lufthansa, SAS, United, Singapore and Malaysian airlines on the other. I.e. all traditional airlines, not budget ones.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your airline (and maybe the airport).

First, I wonder why you need to check your luggage if you have a layover (i.e. a connection)? Did you buy two separate tickets? If you bought BKK-DUB flights on the same tickets, your luggage should be transferred automatically to Dublin, you should not collect them in CDG.

Otherwise, you should go to your airline (selling airline) website, look for "Check-in time" on the website and figure when it is open. It usually opens 2 to 3 hours before departure depending on the distance, but some airlines offer to check the baggage 24 hours before departure (Lufthansa in some German airports for example)