# How is the baggage handled for multicity flights with China Airlines?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, connecting-flights, tpe, china-airlines

I'm looking to book following multicity flights with China Airlines:

1. Bangkok to Taipei
2. Taipei to London

My question is when I arrive at Taipei do I have to collect my luggage and check it in again for outbound trip to London? Or I only check it in at Bangkok and collect it when I get to London?

Edited: To clarify, I intentionally search for the 2 flights from the 'multi-city' option rather than searching for a Bangkok-London flight with a layover in Taipei. So I want to have more than 24 hours in Taipei.

Comment: The term "multi-city" usually implies you're doing a stopover for more than one day in Taipei, can you confirm if this is what you meant?

Comment: Added clarification to the post.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have booked this as a regular itinerary and your layover in TPE is less than 24 hours, **your bags will be checked through directly to London** and you will not need to pick them up and recheck them.

If you have intentionally booked your flights as separate (stopover/multi-city), you will have to collect on arrival and re-check on departure.

Comment: Technically the check through has less to do with the length of the layover but how it is booked. You can actually book a real "multi-city" itinerary with less than 24 hours of stopover and you bags will still be unloaded.

Comment: The edit to the Question now suggests that the OP will be in Taipei for more than 24 hours. Presumably the OP will have to enter Taiwan, collect luggage, and re-drop it with the airline...perhaps on the day of entry, perhaps on the subsequent day of departure. [This previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159168/how-can-i-know-if-my-airline-will-check-my-bags-through-all-the-itinerary?rq=1) may be useful.